# c++ random number and wait parent to all children when process

Tags: c++, c, process

this is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        if((pid()==fork())==0){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(pid==0) { 
        // son process
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand()%4+1;
        cout<<"pid:"<<getpid() <<"num": "<<r<<endl;
    }
    else{ 
        //parent process
    }

}
```

I have problem trandom number same to all process, how i can reset the rand()?
 I have already tried to make different srand() to each process it not works.

Comment: `if((pid()==fork())==0)`  - this construct is funny...And I doubt this code will compile.

Comment: You need to give a different argument to `srand()` in each process if you want them to get different random numbers. Since all the processes start at the same time, `time(NULL)` will be the same.

Comment: You should just ask one question at a time, not 3 different questions.

Comment: i.e to first process give srand(2), the second srand(3) and etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put `time(NULL)+getpid()` to diffrent seed for all rands;
2. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

Comment: let's assume, i wanna all the process run in specific time, 10 seconds for until they finish their running. should i declare variable above the creation and make while loop, if yes, where?